# Ipsec VPN connection with local id

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

In forticlient (using Windows) there is an Ipsec option and you can fill in local id, but linux doesn`t have Ipsec option in forticlient. Is there an alternative to use ipsec via linux and so I could fill in the local id. The closest thing that I found is network-manager-l2tp, it has Ipsec, but I can't find where to fill in the local id.
[Forticlient (windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIx7Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

FortiGate seems to be a clone of Cisco IPsec, so it would seem the `vpnc` client would be appropriate to use, but as it is not a complete clone, the Cisco `vpnc` client needs a FortiGate compatibility patch :

- https://github.com/hekar/vpnc-fortigate

You could then use NetworkManager-vpnc with that patched `vpnc` for the backend.

Alternatively instead of using IPsec, you could try using the `openfortivpn` backend with NetworkManager-fortisslvpn for the UI frontend:

- https://blogs.gnome.org/lkundrak/2015/09/24/fortigate-ssl-vpn-support-added-to-networkmanager/

Comment: You can use the Wayback Machine to see the orphaned link that has more details http://web.archive.org/web/20161027154701/http://www.justdailynotes.com/fortinet/linux/vpn/2015/02/14/Fortigate-IPSec-Linux-NetworkManager/